# optimizing select query from one small table and one large table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using PHP , MySQL for the following
I have two tables

1. users
2. users_messages

The table "users" stores records of all users .

```
id  name  password
1   XYZ   XYZ
```

[Here id is actually the user_id]

The table "messages" contains messages posted by users

```
id  user_id messages
1   1       XYZ
```

The "users" table contains thousands of records (>5000)
The "users_messages" contains about 100 records (will keep on varying)

I am trying to get the no of messages of all the users and show them in a table . 
Currently i am trying to paginate them so i need only 20 users at one page load.

I have my query as follows

```
SELECT u.username as username,u.id as id, COUNT( f.user_id ) AS no_of_messages 
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN users_messages AS f ON f.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id LIMIT 20
```

This works , but it takes a long time ... may be it scans the complete table just to get the no of messages of only 20 users .

The id column of table "users" does not start from 1 , the start is random , but it auto increments from the next record .

Comment: see if indexing is enabled on users table. Mind posing output of `explain users`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The id column of table "users" does not start from 1 , the start is
>   random

Try this instead:

```
SELECT 
  u.username as username, 
  u.id as id, 
  f.no_of_messages 
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) no_of_messages 
   FROM users_messages
   GROUP BY user_id
) AS f ON f.user_id = u.id
ORDER BY u.id
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: how about using use `distinct u.username` and `having count(u.id) = 20`?

Comment: He is looking for `LIMIT 20` for pagination not a `HAVING` clause, and yes it might need to use the `DISTINCT.